# Get number of pages for FPDF unicode version

Tags: php, unicode, fpdf

I have a already implemented code for generate PDF with chinese font. There are some PHP libs which are finally extended by FPDF Lib.

MYPdf -> PDF_Unicode -> PDF_Chinese -> PDF_MC_Table -> FPDF

Now problem is to get total number of pages to display at footer. I checkout {nb} worked with AliasNbPages function. But it did not work and display {nb} constant. 
On some googling I get link http://www.phpfreaks.com/blog/ufpdf-quick-and-dirty-fix-for-page-numbering. But this is too not working ( perhaps due to not using updf lib for unicode. ).

Any body faced this type of issue before and get any solution ?

Links for Third Party Libs for

[PDF_MC_Table] http://www.fpdf.de/downloads/addons/3/

Comment: Due to Spam Prevention Block by Stak Overflow I need to give first link in main question, And rest two links in this comment.
[PDF_Chinese] http://www.phpkode.com/source/p/simtrain/simtrain-1.20/modules/simtrain/fpdf/chinese.php

[PDF_Unicode] http://www.phpkode.com/source/p/simtrain/simtrain-1.20/modules/simtrain/fpdf/chinese-unicode.php

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?820592-fpdf-unicode

Comment: I did not understand if this link have any solution or even have same problem as mine. I have unicode work fine with content but problem for total page number variable usage as {nb} not works with unicode libs for FPDF.